# Tree with context menu using JSF 2.0 and Hibernate

Tags: tree, jsf-2

I need to implement a content tree with context menu (add, delete, edit) in JSF 2.0. Please suggest me some components. The tree node should be an object like (Data, ID). When I click on tree node I need to get the id to backend bean.

Example:

## index.xhtml

Prime Tree

```
        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />


        <p:tree value="#{treeBean.root}" var="node" id="pTree"
                selectionMode="single" selection="#{treeBean.selectedNode}">

            <p:treeNode>
                <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
            </p:treeNode>
        </p:tree>
        <p:contextMenu for="pTree" id="cmenu">
            <p:menuitem value="Add topic as child" update="pTree, cmenu"
                        actionListener="#{treeBean.addChildNode}" />
             <p:menuitem value="Add topic Below" update="pTree, cmenu"
                        actionListener="#{treeBean.addTopicBelow}" />
             <p:menuitem value="Delete Topic" update="pTree, cmenu"
                        actionListener="#{treeBean.deleteNode}" />
        </p:contextMenu>

    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

## TreeBean.java

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package com.prime.tree;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultTreeNode;
import org.primefaces.model.TreeNode;

/**
 *
 * @author Veerendra
 */
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TreeBean implements Serializable {

```
private TreeNode root;

private TreeNode selectedNode;

public TreeBean() {
    root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);
    List rootNodes<Employee> = SearchDao.getRootNodes();

    Iterator it = rootNodes.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {

        TreeNode node1 = new DefaultTreeNode(**it.next()**, root);
        **/* in place of it.next() I need to display empName. When I click on empName, I need to get the Id(Pkey). */**

    }

}

public TreeNode getRoot() {
    return root;
}

public TreeNode getSelectedNode() {
    return selectedNode;
}

public void setSelectedNode(TreeNode selectedNode) {
    this.selectedNode = selectedNode;
}



public void addChildNode(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    System.out.println("Selected Node: "+getSelectedNode().toString());
    TreeNode newNode = new DefaultTreeNode("Node New", getSelectedNode());
    getSelectedNode().setExpanded(true);
}
public void addTopicBelow(ActionEvent actionEvent){
    TreeNode newNode = new DefaultTreeNode("Node New", getSelectedNode().getParent());
}
public void deleteNode(ActionEvent actionEvent){
     System.out.println("Node to be deleted: "+getSelectedNode().toString());
     //getSelectedNode().
}
```

}

## Employee.java

public class Employee{

```
private String empID;
private String empName;

/**
 * @return the empName
 */
public String getEmpName() {
    return empName;
}

/**
 * @param empName the empName to set
 */
public void setEmpName(String empName) {
    this.empName = empName;
}

/**
 * @return the empID
 */
public String getEmpID() {
    return empID;
}

/**
 * @param empID the empID to set
 */
public void setEmpID(String empID) {
    this.empID = empID;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at the [Primefaces Tree](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tree.jsf) component in combination with the [ContextMenu](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/contextMenu.jsf).

You can build your tree in the backing bean and get the selected node as described in the examples of the Primefaces showcase.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thank you for the reply. I have already used PrimeFaces 2.2. But, I was not able to represent the data properly. ex: TreeNode node0 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0", root);  Instead of "Node 0" I need to represent an object. (Id, data, index, etc..).

Comment: The [DefaultTreeNode class](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/core/trunk/src/main/java/org/primefaces/model/DefaultTreeNode.java?r=2776) has a constructor `public DefaultTreeNode(Object data, TreeNode parent)`. So you can put any object as data not only String.

Comment: If I put an object obj1(Id, data, sortIndex, content). The tree is not displaying.

Comment: Could you update your answer with some code of the facelet and the bean?

Comment: Use `<h:outputText value="#{node.empName}" />` in your `p:treeNode` tag instead of referencing the node.

Comment: Hi Matt, I am able to see the tree now. Thank you.  I wanted to to know is there any possibility to highlight a particular tree node from backend.

Comment: Good to hear it works! You could start a new question with the highlight issue. You'd get more attention (and problably better answers ;-)

Comment: Ok.. Thank you. I will start a new question.